# Code Error showing LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol after introducing parameterized constructors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-c++, constructor

I am trying to set a principal amount with class constructors and begin getting this error.

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Bond::Bond(double,double,double,char)" (??0Bond@@QAE@NNND@Z) referenced in function _main

Attached my code below. Would appreciate if anybody can point out what the error is. Thanks in advance.

```
// bond.cpp file

    Bond::Bond(double prin, double rat, double yTM, char typ)
    {
        cout << "I have created a tailored Bond" << endl;
        setPrincipal(prin);
    }

    void Bond::setPrincipal(double prin)
    {
        principal = prin;
    }

    double Bond::getPrincipal()
    {
        return principal;
    }

    //main.cpp 
    int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
    {
        Bond complexBond(999.99, 0.05, 10, 'S');

        cout << "complexBond.getPrincipal(): " << complexBond.getPrincipal() << endl;
        return 0; 
    }

//bond.h header file
class Bond
{
public:
    Bond();

    Bond(double, double, double, char);

    void setPrincipal(double);

    double getPrincipal();

private:
    double principal;
    double rate;
    double yearsToMaturity;
    char paymentType; // 'A'nnual, 'S'emi-Annual, 'Q'uarterly
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the `#inlcudes` that you are using in your code please?

Comment: Check that bond.cpp is getting compiled. The linker is complaining it can't find the definition of the constructor of `Bond`.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. I am a beginner trying to pick up C++. Can i check how do i know if bond.cpp is being compiled?

Answer (score 0):

LNK2019 is usually caused by two things:

1. The source file that contains the definition of the symbol isn't compiled
2. A function is used but the type or number of the parameters don't match the function definition.

When I copy your code and run it, the error doesn’t appear. So, I guess that bond.h isn’t included in bond.cpp. You just add `#include "bond.h"` at the top of bond.cpp.

If the solution doesn’t solve your problem, you could refer to [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019)